# Inner Hashtable Overwriting

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I'm working on the hashtable.In which i wanna form hashtable but my values of the outer hashtable getting replaced.

Hashtable1[key,Hashtable[key,value]]

Im able to get the outerhashtable key without overwriting but the inner hashtable values getting replaced .

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import com.sridhar.util.*;

 public class MyTokenizerDemo 
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht1=new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht2=new Hashtable();
    File f = new File("E:/rum/format.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;
    while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        ArrayList aList = (ArrayList)StringUtils.myTokenizer(s,"~!~");
        for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++)
        {
            ArrayList aList1 = (ArrayList)StringUtils.myTokenizer((String)aList.get(i),"$#$");
            //System.out.println("==>"+aList1.get(0)+"<==");
            ArrayList aList2 = (ArrayList)StringUtils.myTokenizer((String)aList1.get(1),"~$~");
            //System.out.println("====>"+aList2+"<=====");
            for(int j=0;j<aList2.size();j++)
            {
                ArrayList as = (ArrayList)StringUtils.MyTokenizer((String)aList2.get(j),"#$#");
                if(as!=null)
                {
                String innerkey = (String)as.get(0);
                String innervalue = (String)as.get(1);
                ht2.put(innerkey,innervalue);
                }
            }
        ht1.put(aList1.get(0),ht2);
        }
    }
     System.out.println(ht1);
   }
```

}

Kindly make an assumption on my own string tokenizing utility class.

My outer Hashtable values are overwriting.

Help me out in this issue.

Comment: For the love of James Gosling, stop using Hashtable and start using Generics. This code was out of date circa 2004.

Comment: cool brian :)hereon, will do that for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify this lin of code `ht1.put(aList1.get(0),ht2);`  as `ht1.put(aList1.get(i),ht2);`

When you call the asList1.get(0) always key will be same, so your data will be overrides

Comment: oops!! my key is changing properly but i could nt get the key,values of ht2 properly it nly overwrites ...

Comment: The same logic applies over there as well, you need to change String innerkey = (String)as.get(0);String innervalue = (String)as.get(1); to String innerkey = (String)as.get(j);String innervalue = (String)as.get(j+1);

Answer (score 0):

I done simple mistake here !! instantiation inside the for loop makes the values to remain alive instead of overwriting !! thanks all !! below is the code !

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.sridhar.util.*;

public class MyTokenizerDemo 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
Hashtable ht1=new Hashtable();
Hashtable ht2=new Hashtable();
File f = new File("E:/rum/format.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String s;
while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    ArrayList aList = (ArrayList)StringUtils.myTokenizer(s,"~!~");
    for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++)
    {
        ht2 = new Hashtable();   //Instantiating inside the loop makes to work perfect :)
        ArrayList aList1 = (ArrayList)StringUtils.myTokenizer((String)aList.get(i),"$#$");
        //System.out.println("==>"+aList1.get(0)+"<==");
        ArrayList aList2 = (ArrayList)StringUtils.myTokenizer((String)aList1.get(1),"~$~");
        //System.out.println("====>"+aList2+"<=====");
        for(int j=0;j<aList2.size();j++)
        {
            ArrayList as = (ArrayList)StringUtils.MyTokenizer((String)aList2.get(j),"#$#");
            if(as!=null)
            {
            String innerkey = (String)as.get(0);
            String innervalue = (String)as.get(1);
            ht2.put(innerkey,innervalue);
            }
        }
    ht1.put(aList1.get(0),ht2);
    }
}
 System.out.println(ht1);
}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest that you use parameterized generic types and enhanced for loops.